# SUMPRODUCT function of conditionally formatted cells

Tags: excel, vba, function, excel-formula, user-defined-functions

I have a list of prices (which vary) starting on M13 and every 3 columns to the right until CJ13, I wanted to highlight the lowest price by row with conditional formatting so I implemented the formula:

`=AND(COUNT($M13:$CJ13)<>0,M13=MIN($M13:$CJ13))`

which worked perfectly.

Now I want to get the result of SUMPRODUCT by column of the highlighted cells (M, P, etc) with the corresponding value  in column H (column H will never move). So it would be: the highlighted value multiplied by the value on the same row on column H, plus the next highlihted value multiplied by its corresponding in column H, etc.

I would appreciate any help, UDF or function or any idea on how to do it. 
I believe the reason it has been difficut lies in the conditional formatting since a color based criteria will read the color behind the CF (background color which is blue) and not the CF color (green Colorindex=43).

Comment: Use a helper column in which you put the MIN formula for each row, then use SUMPRODUCT on that column and column H.

Comment: Hard to tell without a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but perhaps you coud [`transpose`](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/transpose.php) the data to treat it like a column?